# Entropy maximization in the Multivariate Normal Distribution

Tags: multivariable-calculus, entropy

I am trying to derive the entropy in multivariate normal distribution. Let $p(X)$, $X\in\Re^{n\times 1}$ to be the probability density function of multivariate normal distribution such that
\begin{equation}
p(x) = (2\pi)^{-\frac{n}{2}} \det(\Sigma)^{-\frac{1}{2}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(X-\mu)^\top\Sigma^{-1}(X-\mu)}
\end{equation}
So the entropy $H$ is defined by
\begin{equation}
H = -\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} p(X) \log(p(X))dX = \frac{n}{2}\log(2\pi)\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} p(X) dX +\frac{1}{2}\log( \det(\Sigma)) \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} p(X) dX + \frac{1}{2} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} p(X) (X-\mu)^\top\Sigma^{-1}(X-\mu) dX
\end{equation}
Because
\begin{equation}
\frac{dp(X)}{dX} = p(X) (X-\mu)^\top\Sigma^{-1},
\end{equation}
we have
\begin{equation}
H  = \frac{n}{2}\log(2\pi) +\frac{1}{2}\log( \det(\Sigma)) + \frac{1}{2} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{dp(X)}{dX} (X-\mu) dX
\end{equation}

Can anyone know how to solve this integration problem?
\begin{equation}
\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{dp(X)}{dX} X dX
\end{equation}
by using integration by parts, maybe? Many thanks!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2029707

Comment: Many thanks, I know I can solve it using the expectation method, I was wondering, is it possible to solve it by integration?

Comment: Of course one could do that, for example by transforming into spherical coordinates. $\Sigma^{-1/2}(x-\mu) = z = r\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\sin(\varphi_k)$. But essentially it will boil down to a derivation of the variance of a normal distribution.